# Mavensmate Allman Style

Tags: mavensmate

Recently I got a new position and it is required by lead to use allman style of formatting, currently I am using Sublime text 3 and AStyler but I am not able to get to change the formatting from `} else {` to

```
}
 else
{
```

Has anyone figured this out and can share their default settings?  Or can anyone recommend in using a different code styler.

Comment: you might want to post in stackoverflow instead to get more eyes. I think its more of a sublimetext question than mavensmate.

Comment: It seems like I'm having a issue with the config because it is trying to find Apex